# Sign In with Apple Validation

Tags: java, ios, spring, expo, apple-sign-in

Hi I am building an app using react native and expo. I have [apple-authentication](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v40.0.0/sdk/apple-authentication/) in the expo docs to handle the frontend. Now I want to validate the response in the backend which is in Java. According to the expo docs, the response from apple contains an `authorizationCode` and `identityToken`. My question is do I need to create a new JWT in the backend or should I use the `identityToken` from the frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, You need to decode identityToken using JWT decoder to verify the payload and signature.

And then, you should get a access token using authorizationCode and client_secret from Apple REST API.

client_secret is a JWT that you have to create to request a access token, and it needs your app's private key issued by apple developer configuration.